# Three variables in for...in loop using Swift

Tags: swift, for-in-loop

I was able to implement a `for ... in` loop in Swift for two variables using the `zip()` function:

```
for (i, j) in zip(1...number, 2...number + 1)
```

Now, I am trying to implement a `for ... in` loop in Swift for three variables using `zip()`, but it is giving errors:

```
for (i, j, k) in zip(1...number, 2...number + 1, 3...number + 2)
```

The error I am getting when using zip:

> main.swift:8:51: error: extra argument in call
>       for (i, j, k) in zip(1...number, 2...number + 1, 3...number + 2)

I also tried omitting the `zip()` function, but I am still getting errors:

```
for (i, j, k) in (1...number, 2...number + 1, 3...number + 2)
```

The error I am getting without using `zip()`:

> main.swift:8:18: error: type '(ClosedRange, ClosedRange, ClosedRange)' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
>       for (i, j, k) in (1...number, 2...number + 1, 3...number + 2)

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please include the error(s) in your question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`zip(_:_:)`** doesn't work with more than 2 arguments.

> func zip(_ sequence1: Sequence1, _ sequence2:
>   Sequence2) -> Zip2Sequence where Sequence1 :
>   Sequence, Sequence2 : Sequence

You need to combine multiple `zip(_:_:)` to get that working.

**Example:**

```
for ((i, j), k) in zip(zip(1...number, 2...number + 1), 3...number + 2) {
    print(i, j, k)
}
```